# "You are the highest seniority level that I've ever known"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I have a friend who is a software engineer that has a really high seniority level at his company and I want to tell him that he has the highest seniority level in my social circle. I was wondering how I can say that. I figured there could a few ways:

1. You are the highest seniority level engineer that I've ever known
2. You has the highest seniority level among the engineers that I know

Can someone please tell me which one is better and any other suggestion for saying this?

Answer (score -1):

So I think the second option sounds more natural, except it needs to be "You have the highest seniority level", not "has". The first one is okay except the phrase "highest seniority level engineer" can sound a little awkward but there is nothing actually wrong with the first option. You could also phrase this like "You're the most senior engineer I know" "You have the most seniority of any engineer I've met" "You are the engineer I know with the most seniority" "You are the engineer I know at the highest level" and the way that you phrased it, "You have the highest seniority level in my social circle."

Comment: shouldn't "You have the most seniority of any engineer I've met" be "You have the most seniority *than* any engineer I've met"?

Comment: No! Fun question. I think you either have to say "You have the most seniority of any engineer I've met" or "You have more seniority than any [other] engineer I've met". It does not feel natural to have "the most" *than* something, you can only have the most of something. You may have more of something than someone else, or less than someone else, but not the most than or the least than.